# Question about definition of neighborhood of a point in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, definition

Definition of **neighborhood** of a point $p$:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, then a subset $V$ of $X$ is a **neighborhood** of $p∈X$ if it contains an open set $U$ containing $p$, in other words:
>   $$x∈U⊆V⊆X$$

I was thinking why we require an **open** set $U$, and then I came up with the following example:

Let the real line to be our topological space and consider a subset $\color{BLUE}{V=\left[-1,1\right]}$ of the real line, now if we let $U$ to be a closed set then we can find a point like $\color{RED}{1}$ and a subset $U=\left[0,1\right]$ of $\color{BLUE}{V}$ such that $U$ contains $\color{RED}{1}$ , clearly ignoring the condition to be an open set follows that the interval $\color{BLUE}{V=\left[-1,1\right]}$ is actually a neighborhood of the point $\color{RED}{1}$.

But I'm still not sure that my example is right or that's not the reason why we $U$ to be an open set .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drop the condition that $U$ is open, then *any* subset $V$ of $X$ such that $p\in V$ will be a neighborhood of $p$. Just take $U=V$ or $U=\{p\}$.

Comment: THANKS, is my example also right?

Comment: No. The set $[-1,1]$ is *not* a neighborhood of $1$ since there is no open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $1\in U$ and $U\subset[-1,1]$.

Comment: I got it,is there any connection between a neighborhood and openness of that neighborhood? because I think a subset can be a neighborhood of a set while it is not open itself and there is no require for a neighborhood to be open

Comment: I agree: a neighborhhod doesn't have to be open. For instance, in $\mathbb R$, $[-1,1]$ is a neighborhood of $0$, but it is not an open set.